# Get part of data from cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have a cv::Mat src (type: CV_32F) with size 11000x1085.

Get a row data

```
cv::Mat dst = src.row();
```

If I want to get data from column 4 to 1085, I do this way.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
   for(int j = 3; j < 1085; j++)
      dst.at<double>(i,j-3) = src.at<double>(i,j);
```

Is there another way to do that faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Mat::colRange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-colrange)

```
cv::Mat dst = src.colRange(3, 1085);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you want to make a deep copy of the data or not. You may want to construct a region of interest (ROI) as described on this helpful tutorial, which describes other methods to work with the cv::Mat to structure your data:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

To create a region of interest (ROI) for a rectangle:

```
Mat Dst (src, Rect(3, 0, 11000, 1085) );
```

If you want copy the data:

```
Mat Clone = Dst.clone();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Mat Dst (src, Rect(3, 0, 1085 - 3, 11000) );`?